# How to inline form design yii2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2

How to design inline form design in **yii2** .Actually here I wanna inline form design instead of in build form design in **yii2 framework**

[image]

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'org_code')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'org_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <?= $form->field($model ,'org_name')?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <?= $form->field($model ,'org_name')?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <?= $form->field($model ,'org_name')?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Read more about Bootstrap [Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic) classes

Comment: Thanks this one working but my expected design is different

Comment: make a new row and provide grid column class with different lengths

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Saved me!!